# Want to get youtube ID in referrer domain with PHP? [other answers not working]

Tags: php, youtube, tracking, issue-tracking

I've researched but not found a solution for this situation, please advise!

I want to track where exactly is click from youtube video.
A PHP file named "trackid.php" with following code:

```
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
echo $actual_link;
```

I shortened URL of that file using goo.gl, and place that shortened URL in the description of a Youtube video.

When I try to open the shortened URL, the result is

```
https://www.youtube.com/
```

But I need to get full URL including "watch?v=sampleID", I want to get ID of the video for tracking purpose.

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be presence of this tag in header:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
```

all Referer headers in loads from your document will be without a path, query string or fragment, origin only. There are other policies you can specify to suppress referrers entirely, send a stripped-down referrer string cross-origin, and more.

https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/01/21/meta-referrer/

Comment: youtube is protecting itself and force refferer to youtube.com without any path.